# winforms - how to move a picturebox within a tableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms

i tried to use panels in each cells but the picturebox still wont move to another cell.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(button1);

// then:

tableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(pictureBox, columnIndex, rowIndex);
```

Read about [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx):

[TableLayoutPanel tutorial on csharp-online.net](http://en.csharp-online.net/TableLayoutPanel)

---

If you wanted to implement *Drag and Drop*, you may get used from the following references:

[A Simple Drag And Drop How To Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/dandtutorial.aspx)

[Simple drag and drop example](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/drag-and-drop-example.htm)

Comment: thanks but i wanted to drag and drop within a table. is it possible?

Comment: @gooteis: Sure, but you need to read about drag and drop first. I've edited my answer providing some references